# LuaInterface in C# confusion

Tags: c#, lua

I've used Lua before, as an end user, on several occasions, and I seem to recall being able to make a method in Lua and then registering said method into the program via a RegisterFunction call.

I know that I would have to create the RegisterFunction call inside of my application for this setup to work, but my question is whether or not i have to implement the support for methods inside of Lua myself?

As far as I can tell the only options I have at this point are DoString and DoFile, I can't find any help on this anywhere.

Im attempting to add Lua to my Game Setup for all of the Entity code, I have it setup to allow me to put scripts in at certain Events for each entity type, and I would like to attach Lua methods to those events to call them.

For Example:

```
OnDamagedEvent += DoLuaMethod(method, Entity ID);
```

From my understanding of how any programming works I wouldn't think it would be possible to perform an entire method from just "DoString" unless the string contained the entire method at once, which i suppose it could, but is that how its supposed to be used? I had planned on just Sending one line at a time to the Engine.

If I define a method in Lua will it be permanently (in that instance) defined in lua to be used?

If so, how can I get that methods accessor into C# and later access it, sending the required information to invoke the parameters (the one I recall had specific method TYPES that you had to choose from, so that it knew what information to send to the method)

I apologize if I sound like a total noob for not knowing how to setup something that seems so simple in concept, I'm just not sure how the code should be layed out and what methods from the LuaInterface I should be using!

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found all the answers to my questions.

LuaInterface has a "LuaFunction" class that you can use to referance functions inside lua.

Once a script has been run, any functions that have been initialized will remain initialized after the script has been run.

You can set a LuaFunction object by using Lua.GetFunction(FUNCTION NAME) where Lua referances your instance of Lua that holds the function (after running the script)

I added a few new methods in my Exposed Methods: RegisterEntityEvent and RegisterGlobalEvent with a few paramaters to allow me to be more specific as to which event i want to add this method to, its setup like this:

```
public static void RegisterEntityMethod(string MethodName, string EntityType, string EventType)
{
    EntityTypes[EntityType].Events[EventType] += CallLuaMethod(LuaEngine.LuaVM.GetFunction(name));
}
```

///\
Thats an example ofc, untested

To call it you simply run LuaFunction.Call(Parameters);

That allows me to call methods that are in my Lua scripts from within the event handlers I have in my Game.

It was as easy as I thought it was, just not easy to find somewhere to learn how to do it :D

here: http://forum.junowebdesign.com/net-programming/30025-luainterface-explained.html >